# Computations to build a logic in R

Tags: r, excel, vba, replace, excel-2010

I am trying to cover a logic in excel, however failing since i am not a pro in excel.

Below is how my data looks like:

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 C15
1 12  3  3  4  5  6  7  7  7   7   7   7   7   7   7
2  1  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  6   7   8   8   8   8   8
3  3  4  4  4  4 45 32 57 23  23  23  23  23  23  23
```

As you can see, in the first row, from the last column there are multiple 7's. Similary, for the second row starting from the last column
there are multiple 8's and for row3, there are multiple 23's.

I want to replace the multiple columns of 7's,8's and 23's into #N/A, and keep only the first 7 in my result.
I tried it with a simple logic, where IF(C15<>C14, C15,"N/A"), however this logic fails as it also converts the previous repeated values at row level too

Below is how i am looking for the final result.

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7   C8   C9  C10  C11  C12  C13  C14  C15
1 12  3  3  4  5  6  7 #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A
2  1  4  5  5  5  5  5    5    6    7    8 #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A
3  3  4  4  4  4 45 32   57   23 #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A #N/A
```

Can i do it in excel, or i need to find some code in R?

Any leads would be appreciated.

THanks,
Jay

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c(12, 1, 3), C2 = c(3, 4, 4), C3 = c(3, 5, 4), 
               C4 = c(4, 5, 4), C5 = c(5, 5, 4), C6 = c(6, 5, 45), 
               C7 = c(7, 5, 32), C8 = c(7, 5, 57), C9 = c(7, 6, 23), 
               C10 = c(7, 7, 23), C11 = c(7, 8, 23), C12 = c(7, 8, 23), 
               C13 = c(7, 8, 23), C14 = c(7, 8, 23), C15 = c(7, 8, 23)), 
          .Names = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", 
                     "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10",
                     "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: To replace "in place" you will need VBA. Do you want "in place" or can the result be returned elsewhere on the sheet?

Comment: in place only...

Comment: ^^ Otherwise you can try something like conditional formatting to call out your duplicated values (change cell background to black to hide the value)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an R solution using `rleid` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
df[t(apply(df, 1, function(x) shift(rleid(x) == max(rleid(x)))))] <- NA
```

**Result:**

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 C15
1 12  3  3  4  5  6  7 NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2  1  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  6   7   8  NA  NA  NA  NA
3  3  4  4  4  4 45 32 57 23  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Note that this works even if the repeating integer appears anywhere in each row not connected to the repeating sequence at the end.

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(C1 = c(12L, 1L, 3L), C2 = c(3L, 4L, 4L), C3 = c(3L, 
5L, 4L), C4 = c(4L, 5L, 4L), C5 = c(5L, 5L, 4L), C6 = c(6L, 5L, 
45L), C7 = c(7L, 5L, 32L), C8 = c(7L, 5L, 57L), C9 = c(7L, 6L, 
23L), C10 = c(7L, 7L, 23L), C11 = c(7L, 8L, 23L), C12 = c(7L, 
8L, 23L), C13 = c(7L, 8L, 23L), C14 = c(7L, 8L, 23L), C15 = c(7L, 
8L, 23L)), .Names = c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", 
"C8", "C9", "C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R you can do it like the following.
This is the third version of the function, thanks to @useR for pointing out the wrong results of the others in some use cases.

```
fun <- function(x, n){
  r <- rle(x)
  n <- length(x)
  x[(n - r$lengths[length(r$lengths)] + 2):n] <- NA
  x
}

x <- c(12,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7)
fun(x)
#[1] 12  3  3  4  5  6  7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

y <- c(12,7,7,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7)
fun(y)
#[1] 12  7  7  4  5  6  7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Now with a `data.frame`.

```
dat[] <- t(apply(dat, 1, fun))
#  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 C15
#1 12  3  3  4  5  6  7 NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#2  1  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  6   7   8  NA  NA  NA  NA
#3  3  4  4  4  4 45 32 57 23  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

**Data.**

```
dat <- read.csv(text = "
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15
12,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
1,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8
3,4,4,4,4,45,32,57,23,23,23,23,23,23,23
")
```

Comment: It''s not working. It replaces the previous consecutive values as well in the row. Also for some rows, it is not giving the first 7,8 or 23 before NA.

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text='C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15
12,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
                  1,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8
                  3,4,4,4,4,45,32,57,23,23,23,23,23,23,23', sep = ",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Code:

```
 apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
  x <- rle(x)
  len_x <- length(x$lengths)

  if( (x$lengths)[len_x] > 1 ){ # check for end sequence
    x <- list(lengths = c(x$lengths[-len_x], 1, x$lengths[len_x]- 1 ),
              values = c(x$values, NA))
  } 
  inverse.rle(x)
})
```

Output:

```
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   12    1    3
# [2,]    3    4    4
# [3,]    3    5    4
# [4,]    4    5    4
# [5,]    5    5    4
# [6,]    6    5   45
# [7,]    7    5   32
# [8,]   NA    5   57
# [9,]   NA    6   23
# [10,]   NA    7   NA
# [11,]   NA    8   NA
# [12,]   NA   NA   NA
# [13,]   NA   NA   NA
# [14,]   NA   NA   NA
# [15,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: 7,8 and 23 are the examples i have given. there can be n numbers in the data.. Your code will work only for 7,8 and 23.

Comment: it will also work if there is no end sequence in the data

Answer (score 0):

Before:

[image]

the code:

```
Sub marine()
    For i = 2 To 4
        For j = 15 To 2 Step -1
            If Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j - 1).Value Then
                Cells(i, j).Value = "#N/A"
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this only uses one loop:

```
Sub nadup()

With Worksheets("Sheet5") 'change to your sheet
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 4
        Dim t As Long
        t = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 15), Range(i & ":" & i), 0)
        If t < 14 Then
            .Range(.Cells(i, t + 1), .Cells(i, 15)).Value = "N/A"
        ElseIf t = 14 Then
            .Cells(i, 15) = "N/A"
        End If
    Next i
End With



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

With arrays

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReplaceItems()
    Dim arr(), arr2(), i As Long, j As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        arr() = .Range("A1:O3").Value
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr, 2))
            For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
                If IsError(Application.Match(arr(i, j), arr2, 0)) Then
                    arr2(j) = arr(i, j)
                Else
                    Select Case arr(i, j)
                    Case 7, 8, 23
                    arr2(j) = "#N/A"
                    Case Else
                    arr2(j) = arr(i, j)
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
            .Range("A" & i).Resize(1, UBound(arr2)).Value = arr2
        Next i
    End With
End Su
```